# Continue in method if Element is not visible

Tags: c#, selenium, element

I am testing a UI with C#/Selenium and there is a data entry section, followed by a results window.  There are either results returned, or no results returned.  I am testing both scenarios

I created a method for this testing as below.   This can be used to either test Yes/No scenarios whether an element exists or not...

```
    public bool HasResults()
    {

            IList<IWebElement> yesResultElement = _driver.FindElements(yesResults);

            if (yesResultElement.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }


            IList<IWebElement> noResultElement = _driver.FindElements(noResults);
        
            if (noResultElement.Count > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

        throw new Exception("Could not determine if there were results");

    }
```

The problem is, when I am testing for 'noResultElement', this method is getting hung up and timing out because it can't find the 'yesResultElement'.

I tried adding a try/catch around the first IF statement

```
    public bool HasResults()
    {
        try
        {

            IList<IWebElement> yesResultElement = _driver.FindElements(yesResults);

            if (yesResultElement.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("element does not exist");
        }

        IList<IWebElement> noResultElement = _driver.FindElements(noResults);
        
        if (noResultElement.Count > 0){
            return false;
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not determine if there were results");

    }
```

That resolves the issue, but it also turns a 20 second test into > 1 min  (due to Implicit Wait specified in Test file)

Aside from splitting this into 2 methods, is there a better way to handle this?  if yesResultElement is not present, ignore that IF statement and move onto the next one, is what I want.

The Tests look like this

`[TestMethod]`

```
    public void NoRecordsFoundTest()
    {
        // Tests whether no records are found when that is the expected outcome
        var searchPage = new SearchPage(driver);
        var firstTest = testData.First();
        searchPage.EnterSearchInfo(firstTest);
        var result = searchPage.HasResults();
        try
        {
            result.Should().BeFalse();
            log.Debug("The No Records Found Test Passed");
        }
        catch (AssertFailedException ex)
        {
            log.Debug("The No Records Found Test Failed",ex);
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }


    [TestMethod]

    public void RecordsFoundTest()
    {

        // Tests whether records are found when that is the expected outcome

        var searchPage = new SearchPage(driver);
        var firstTest = testData.Skip(1).First();
        searchPage.EnterSearchInfo(firstTest);
        var result = searchPage.HasResults();
        try
        {
            result.Should().BeTrue();
            log.Debug("The Records Found Test Passed");
        }
        catch (AssertFailedException ex)
        {
            log.Debug("The Records Found Test Failed", ex);
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

Not sure its relevant but test data is loaded from JSON file and passed into EnterSearchInfo() method.

Also, one glitch in the UI is even if results are returned, for a split second the noResultElement appears, and then goes away.

Comment: Can you add more code that includes the method call, any waits/loops and value of yesResults, noResults?  Doesn't seem like you'd need two checks here, though.

Comment: @pcalkins  Just added the tests themselves, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily set the implicit wait timeout to some small value, repeatedly try to find your elements, waiting until at least one group is found (using `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait`), then return a boolean value depending on which group was found.

An extension method like this may be helpful:

```cs
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the specified `action` with `ImplicitWait` set to the specified `timeout`.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The action return type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="b">The WebDriver instance.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">
    /// The duration that WebDriver should implicitly wait until it gives up on trying to
    /// find an element.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="action">
    /// The action to execute with the special ImplicitWait setting.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>The action result.</returns>
    public static T WithImplicitWait<T>(this ChromeDriver b, TimeSpan timeout, Func<T> action)
    {
        ITimeouts timeouts = b.Manage().Timeouts();
        TimeSpan oldImplicitWait = timeouts.ImplicitWait;
        try
        {
            timeouts.ImplicitWait = timeout;
            return action();
        }
        finally
        {
            timeouts.ImplicitWait = oldImplicitWait;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```cs
public bool HasResults()
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    {
        Message = "Could not find neither 'yes' nor 'no' results."
    };
    var implicitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    string found =_driver.WithImplicitWait(implicitTimeout, () => wait.Until(b =>
    {
        IList<IWebElement> yesResultElement = _driver.FindElements(yesResults);
        IList<IWebElement> noResultElement = _driver.FindElements(noResults);
        if (yesResultElement.Count == 0 && noResultElement.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (yesResultElement.Count > 0 && noResultElement.Count > 0)
        {
            return "both";
        }

        return yesResultElement.Count > 0 ? "yes" : "no";
    }));
    bool result = found switch
    {
        "yes" => true,
        "no" => false,
        _ => throw new Exception("Could not determine if there were results")
    };
    return result;
}
```

`WebDriverWait.Until` will repeatedly call your callback until it returns a non-null value, therefore we return `null` when neither group is found. It will give up after (in this case) 10 seconds and fail with the specified error message.